# change angular state according to the URL parameter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing

Hi in my app I have two states called `hello` and `createHello`

Modules related to thees two states are given below.

createHello Module

```
(function(module){
    'use strict';

    module.config(['$stateProvider',
        function($stateProvider) {
            $stateProvider.state('createHello', {
                url: '/hello/create',
                templateUrl: 'app/createHello/createHello.html',
                controller: 'createHello'
            });
        }
    ]);

})(angular.module('createHello', ['header', 'ui.router', 'timeliner','common']));
```

hello Module

```
(function (module) {
    'use strict';

    module.config(['$stateProvider',
        function ($stateProvider) {
            $stateProvider.state('hello', {
                url: '/hello/{id}',
                templateUrl: 'app/hello/hello.html',
                controller: 'hello',
                resolve: {
                    .....
                }
            });
        }
    ]);

})(angular.module('hello', ['header', 'ui.router', 'helloTimer', 'logger', 'timeliner', 'common']));
```

Any url pattern of `/hello/xxxx` will go to the `hello` state. I want this specific url (`/hello/create`) to go to the `createHello`state. At the moment it will also go to the `hello` state. Any advice on how to solve this issue?

Comment: you should check difference between `$routeProvider` and `$stateProvider`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Parth. I started reading it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should used nested states.

```
module.config(['$stateProvider',
    function($stateProvider) {
      $stateProvider
        .state('hello', {
          url: '/hello',
          abstract: true,
          template: '<ui-view/>'
        })
        .state('hello.create', {
          url: '/create',
          templateUrl: 'app/createHello/createHello.html',
          controller: 'createHello'
        })
        .state('hello.display', {
          url: '/:id',
          templateUrl: 'app/hello/hello.html',
          controller: 'hello'
        });
    }
]);
```

Note that routing is done on "first match", so you will need to have your /hello/create route declared before the /hello/:id route.

You can read more on how nesting works here:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views

In the example above I used an [abstract](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views#abstract-states) parent state.

Comment: In my case problem got solved when I load the createHello module before the hello module. Thanks for the suggestion @oznu.